# Unable to update itemfrom Data-grid "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, mvvm

I have an issue in regards to my application, and not selecting an item for it to get updated using EF.

I'm creating an application for a user to enter in their organisation details. Seems simple enough. After data has been entered using a tab control, I have a view that contains a series of data grids, giving the user the ability to update, or insert another piece of data if required or have the ability to delete.

within my view-model I have a series of different things (which may not be the best way of implementing MVVM but trying to get there eventually).

I have my properties implementing `INOTIFYPROPERTYCHANGE`. Commands to save, update and delete. And my entity methods (CRUD opererations using Entity Framework - Will use a Repository system later on when I learn more about MVVM etc).

So far, I'm having to use the code-behind of the view to load my data which works perfectly (obviously I shouldn't be doing this so any advice to show me otherwise would be much appreciated) like so;

```
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DBEntities context = new DBEntities();

        var orgTypeDetails = (from o in context.OrganisationTypeDetails
                              select o).ToList();

        dgOrgTypeDetail.ItemsSource = orgTypeDetails;
    }
```

I also have a event-handler which only allows you to select a row and then to update that specific row;

```
    private void btnUpdateOrgTypeDetail_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OrganisationTypeDetailViewModel org = new OrganisationTypeDetailViewModel();

        OrganisationTypeDetail selected = dgOrgTypeDetail.SelectedItem as OrganisationTypeDetail;

        if (selected == null)
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a 'Type' before updating.");
        else
        {
            OrganisationTypeDetailUpdateView update = new OrganisationTypeDetailUpdateView();

            update.ShowDialog();
    org.UpdateOrganisationTypeDetail(selected);
            Page_Loaded(null, null);
        }
    }
```

and finally, my method in which updates the table using EF from View-Model;

```
    public void UpdateOrganisationTypeDetail(OrganisationTypeDetail orgTypeDetail)
    {
        using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
        {
            //var orgTD = context.OrganisationTypeDetails.Where(otd => otd.OrganisationTypeDetailID == OrganisationTypeDetailID).FirstOrDefault();

            var orgTD = (from a in context.OrganisationTypeDetails
                         where a.OrganisationTypeDetailID == OrganisationTypeDetailID
                         select a).FirstOrDefault();

            orgTD.OrganisationTypeDetailID = OrganisationTypeDetailID;
            orgTD.OrganisationTypeID = OrganisationTypeID;
            orgTD.Title = Title;
            orgTD.FirstName = FirstName;
            orgTD.Surname = Surname;
            orgTD.Position = Position;
            orgTD.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
            orgTD.Address = Address;
            orgTD.Country = Country;
            orgTD.Postcode = Postcode;
            orgTD.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            orgTD.MobileNumber = MobileNumber;
            orgTD.FaxNumber = FaxNumber;
            orgTD.Email = Email;
            orgTD.NINumber = NINumber;

            context.OrganisationTypeDetails.ApplyCurrentValues(orgTD);
            context.SaveChanges();

            MessageBox.Show("Updated Organisation Type Details");
        }
```

When executing this application, it produces a `Null Reference exception`.

In my properties, to ensure that it doesn't crash, I have had to set programmatically the ID's;
`public int _OrganisationTypeDetailID=17;`
But I want to be able to select a row at my choice, rather then only having the option to get the row from 17.

I've tried using both Linq and Lamba expressions but neither seem to work.

Sorry if there's a lot to take in from reading this and would happy add more code or explanation if required :).

Comment: did you try to debug? in which line are you getting null reference?

Comment: Yes I have. I get the error on the line of `orgTD.OrganisationTypeDetailID = OrganisationTypeDetailID;` Like I say, If i don't assign it to a `int`in my properties (17, for example) it throws this `error` due to the fact it doesn't know what its trying to update. So I don't know how to change it :S.

Comment: orgTD is null, because FirstOrDefault returns null, it definitely because there is no such record in db

Comment: so how do I change it so that it doesn't return null and returns the row in which is required?

Comment: it depends what you want to do if the record doesn't exists in db, I guess you should just return, so put if(orgTD == null) return; after getting FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) returns default value of type if query doesn't return any result, so allays check if the result is null after FirstOrDefault.

It should look something like this

```
 var orgTD = (from a in context.OrganisationTypeDetails
                         where a.OrganisationTypeDetailID == OrganisationTypeDetailID
                         select a).FirstOrDefault();

 if(orgTD == null)
   return;
```

If you are sure, that query returns at least one element, use [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) instead

Comment: when doing this, it produces this; `Warning 1 The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'`. Should I have to create a method which selects the ID being selected in order for it to update without throwing exceptions?

Comment: it should be orgTD, not orgID please check

Comment: Now, it doesn't fire the command, and nothing happens. So its not getting the ID to update. BTW, thanks for the help. Anything helpful is much appreciated :).

Comment: you are welcome, that is because record with id OrganisationTypeDetailID doesn't exists in database OrganisationTypeDetails
 table(I guess it is linq query). check how it could happen please

Comment: so your saying my Linq query needs to be changed in order to get the ID for it to update the database? if that's the case, I've been trying to do it all this time, haha ^^. Within my table, the organisationTyeDetailID should exist as an entity within that table.

Comment: you should change linq to return value

Comment: In my properties, if i set the `ID` to a value, it updates that specific value. Which is great. But I don't want to have to give it a value programmatically. I want to to select the row I want from the view.

Comment: I've tried binding my data grid to a `selectType` method like so;    private OrganisationTypeDetail _SelectedType;
public OrganisationTypeDetail SelectedType
{
get
{return _SelectedType;}
set{if (_SelectedType == value)
return;
 _SelectedType = value;
OnPropertyChanged("SelectedType");
}
}... Then bound it like so; SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType, Mode=TwoWay}" ... and for the statement i did this var orgTD = context.OrganisationTypeDetails.FirstOrDefault(otd => otd.OrganisationTypeDetailID == SelectedType.OrganisationTypeDetailID); But still throws the same error.

Comment: I think it is another question @gregory.bmclub

Answer (score 0):

I spent two weeks working a similar issue with a MS Visual Studio .NET data entity model connecting to a MySQL database. After much hair-pulling and searching through StackOverflow, MySQL and MS site forums and help resources, the answer to the null reference error was, as expected, fairly simple, so here it is:

I had installed 64-bit MySQL server BUT MS Visual Studio is all 32-bit.  No matter what app.config changes I made, no matter how I played with my references, no matter how many packages I installed through Nuget, I could not resolve the issue except by uninstalling MySQL 64-bit (make sure you reverse engineer your existing databases to models first, so you can reload them later) and then reinstalling MySQL 32-bit.  After re-creating the databases, rebuilding the data entity model and the data source, the null reference error resolved.

SO... if you're using MySQL with MS Visual studio, make certain you have the 32-bit MySQL product.

(Another thing I did that may or may not have effected the outcome was to install Windows IIS to access localHost - I think this is just a distraction from the real issue, however, so only add this as a last resort).